# How much data can Wikimedia Commons host?

Tags: wikipedia, wikimedia-commons

[Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org) has lots of images, audio files and video files. I was only able to find that it was about 23 TB of data in 2013 ([source](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dump_torrents#Commons)) which was actually hosted.

Is there any more recent information?

Is there any information about how much storage capacity Wikimedia Commons has?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of September 2015, Wikimedia Commons hosts about 62.5 TB of media files (not counting old revisions).

On Wikimedia Commons, there is [a special page](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:MediaStatistics) that provides a breakdown of the total size of Wikimedia Commons by the file-type. Adding them up will give you the total size of Wikimedia Commons. There is also [an SQL query](https://quarry.wmflabs.org/query/4616) that can give you the total size in bytes.

Note that all these statistics refer to only current versions of the file and not the file sizes of older or deleted ones. It is slightly more difficult to obtain the combined size of Wikimedia Commons, though [a graph](https://graphite.wikimedia.org/render/?width=714&height=339&_salt=1415878787.645&from=-4months&target=alias(secondYAxis(swift.eqiad-prod.stats.AUTH_mw.bytes)%2C%22media%20account%20bytes%22)&target=alias(movingAverage(summarize(derivative(swift.eqiad-prod.stats.AUTH_mw.bytes)%2C%221d%22)%2C7)%2C%20%22bytes%20per%20day%22)) suggests about slightly more than 135 TB. It might, however, also include those of other wikis (such as the English Wikipedia).

Comment: Do you know if this is compressed data or raw data? (it might not matter too much for JPG, but I guess it does matter a lot for SVG)

Comment: Although I like this answer (+1), it does not answer how data Wikipedia could host (how much capacity they have).

Comment: This is uncompressed data (as keeping them compressed would be a performance concern). As to your second question, it is *virtually unlimited* as the backend is the Swift media storage. They just [recently added new capacity](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T1268) and have a total capacity of 508 TB.

Comment: Here is a source for "[wikipedia uses swift](http://blog.wikimedia.org/2012/02/09/scaling-media-storage-at-wikimedia-with-swift/)". Thank you!